# SQL Over clause does not work on Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a running total column but the SQL OVER clause seems not to be working on my code, not sure what I am doing wrong. Help appreciated.
This is the code:

```vb
Sub TryWithOver()

    Dim strpath As String, constr As String
    Dim Conn As Object, rs As Object
    Dim fld As Variant

   strpath = Range("PathTry") 'double checked the path exists to a Access file

    ' OPEN CONNECTION '
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strpath & ";"
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rsGeneralData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    Conn.Open constr

    rs.Open "SELECT ID, Name, Department,  Salary, COUNT(Department) OVER(PARTITION BY Department) As DepartmentTotals FROM Table1 ", Conn

    
    Range("C9").Select
    ActiveCell(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
Conn.Close
End Sub
```

And this is the error I get

```
Run-Time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(Department) OVER(PARTITION BY Department)'.
```

The data is this:

| ID | Name | Department | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | IT | 15000 |
| 2 | James | IT | 15000 |
| 3 | Smith | IT | 35000 |
| 4 | Rasol | HR | 15000 |
| 5 | Rakesh | Payroll | 35000 |
| 6 | Pam | IT | 42000 |
| 7 | Stokes | HR | 15000 |
| 8 | Taylor | HR | 67000 |
| 9 | Preety | Payroll | 67000 |
| 10 | Priyanka | Payroll | 55000 |
| 11 | Anurag | Payroll | 15000 |
| 12 | Marshal | HR | 55000 |
| 13 | David | IT | 96000 |

I am trying to do this on an excel sheet, with data from an Access database.
Thanks a lot

Cheers

Comment: Wondering why I am not getting any responses ?

Comment: Hello, anyone out there?